# Rotate a UIView that's already animating w/ rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, transform, calayer

I've been searching around, but couldn't find an answer that seems to address my specific issue.  In my app, I have a custom UIView that animates indefinitely.  It's a piece of seaweed, and the animation is very subtle, to make it look like it's swaying in water.  I do this with CAKeyframeAnimation objects on the `transform.rotation.z` and `position` keys.  These are added to a CAAnimationGroup, which is added as a layer to my UIView, like so:

```
animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[animGroup setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:posAnim, rotateAnim, nil]];
animGroup.duration = prpAnim.duration;
animGroup.repeatCount = prpAnim.repeat;
animGroup.delegate = self;
[animGroup setValue:self forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paper.rot.pos.%d",objID]];
[self.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rot.pos.%d",objID]];
```

I want to further rotate that UIView image (piece of seaweed) when tilting the iPad without disturbing the core animation.  I can do this when it's not animated by keyframe, but when I try to combine the two, it doesn't work and I can't figure it out.

I've tried animating the layer using something like this:

```
CATransform3D rotatePiece3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-(tiltRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
seaweedPiece.layer.transform = rotatePiece3D;
```

But that doesn't work either - only when the animation group is turned off.  It's a 2D app, so I just want it rotate around the z-axis when tilting left or right.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently can't alter the rotation separately while it's being animated, so what I was trying to do won't work.  I ended up changing the animation key to `path`, which allowed me to rotate the view separately using the accelerometer.